# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Time' after using different CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I am working on this one a wile now, in the past I had no problems with the code and interactive plot at al. csv file was stored local. things that changed CSV was manualy adjusted sow without the skiprow function.. now I call the csv from a server and skip the first 5 rows . The thing is now I get an error . This is the df I load (one of them).

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("N:/ASS/503 Niro Soavi/Niro Soavi/NSOA Machines in Holland/Nutricia Zoetermeer/220513 BB17 Data/Measure 22030801_chn1_(Vib-Aux)_RMS.csv", skiprows=5)

    Time;dB;Abs;Unit;Overflow;
17:11:03;66 88; 0   002208004; m/s^2;BO ;
17:11:04;64 72; 0   001721869; m/s^2;BO ;
17:11:05;64 75; 0   001727826; m/s^2;BO ;
17:11:06;64 84; 0   001745822; m/s^2;BO ;
17:11:07;65 07; 0   001792668; m/s^2;BO ;
... ... ...
18:05:37;65 32; 0   001845016; m/s^2;BO ;
18:05:38;65 07; 0   001792668; m/s^2;BO ;
18:05:39;69 20; 0   00288403; m/s^2;BO ;
18:05:40;78 17; 0   008100279; m/s^2;BO ;
18:05:41;74 88; 0   005546256; m/s^2;BO ;
3279 rows × 1 columns
```

and here the code, as you can see i try to load 4 different csv in one plot.

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
from plotly.offline import iplot
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go


df1 = pd.read_csv("N:/ASS/503 Niro Soavi/Niro Soavi/NSOA Machines in Holland/Nutricia Zoetermeer/220513 BB17 Data/Measure 22030801_chn1_(Vib-Aux)_RMS.csv", skiprows=5)
df2 = pd.read_csv("N:/ASS/503 Niro Soavi/Niro Soavi/NSOA Machines in Holland/Nutricia Zoetermeer/220513 BB17 Data/Measure 22030801_chn2_(Vib-X)_RMS.csv", skiprows=5)
df3 = pd.read_csv("N:/ASS/503 Niro Soavi/Niro Soavi/NSOA Machines in Holland/Nutricia Zoetermeer/220513 BB17 Data/Measure 22030801_chn3_(Vib-Y)_RMS.csv", skiprows=5)
df4 = pd.read_csv("N:/ASS/503 Niro Soavi/Niro Soavi/NSOA Machines in Holland/Nutricia Zoetermeer/220513 BB17 Data/Measure 22030801_chn4_(Vib-Z)_RMS.csv", skiprows=5)

trace_one = go.Scatter(
        x=df1.Time,
        y=df1['dB'],
        name= "ch1",
        line= dict(color='forestgreen'),
        opacity= 0.4)

trace_two = go.Scatter(
        x=df2.Time,
        y=df2['dB'],
        name= "ch2",
        line= dict(color='chocolate'),
        opacity= 0.4)

 trace_three = go.Scatter(
        x=df3.Time,
        y=df3['dB'],
        name= "ch3",
        line= dict(color='violet'),
        opacity= 0.4)

trace_four = go.Scatter(
        x=df4.Time,
        y=df4['dB'],
        name= "ch4",
        line= dict(color='red'),
        opacity= 0.4)

#data = [trace_one, trace_two, trace_three, trace_four]
 data = [trace_one]

 layout = dict(
    title= 'BB17 values 220308')

 fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
 iplot(fig, filename = 'BB17outcome220308')
```

this is the error i am running in to

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22328/1558647783.py in <module>
     11 
     12 trace_one = go.Scatter(
---> 13             x=df1.Time,
     14             y=df1['dB'],
     15             name= "ch1",

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Time'
```

could somebody help me out and point me in the right direction?

Comment: check file from `df1` manualy,  does it have column named `Time`?
part of code `df1.Time`  is referencing to such a column, Error message, says such a column is missing

Comment: or simply try adding separator to: `df1 = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", sep=';', skiprows=5)`,
maybe you get just one column instead of multiple, as shown in your original df example at the bottom `3279 rows × 1 columns`

Comment: When I print `print(df.columns)`  I get `Index(['Time;dB;Abs;Unit;Overflow;'], dtype='object')` , FYI i am verry new to this.  adding `sep=';'`, did not make a change.  Thanks for the quick response @NoobVB

Comment: try using the `sep=';'` option while reading the file, as now, all is getting dumped into one.

Comment: Thank you very much! forgot to load it again. your solution helped! `sep=';'`